# Flask consul and consul DNS

Tags: python, flask, consul

I'm trying to learn playing with flask and consul.

Here is my /etc/consul.d/consul.json

{
  "data_dir": "/opt/consul/data",
  "server": true,
  "bind_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "bootstrap_expect": 1,
  "ui": true,
  "domain": "bino.inc",
  "client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "node_name": "node01"
}

run with /usr/bin/consul agent -config-dir=/etc/consul.d/

Test with dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 node01.node.bino.inc and got 
;; ANSWER SECTION:
node01.node.bino.inc.   0   IN  A   192.168.1.5

I just make a copy of example from https://github.com/vsudilov/flask-consulate
make a small change to it :

```
# Register Consul service:
consul.register_service(
    address='127.0.0.1',
    name='webapp',
    interval='10s',
    tags=['master', ],
    port=5000,
    httpcheck='http://localhost:5000/healthcheck'
)
```

consul.app.run(port=5000, threaded = False, debug=True)

Looks like consul and flask script communicating each other.
flask debug got :

> 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2018 08:38:27] "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 -

My question is the FQDN of my flask script that consul will generate ?

I tried

> dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 webapp.bino.inc

, and consul debug said :

> 2018/11/15 08:41:29 [WARN] dns: QName invalid: webapp.

Tried with

> dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 webserver.bino.inc

, consul debug said :

> 2018/11/15 08:43:37 [WARN] dns: QName invalid: webserver.

Sincerely
-bino-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querying registered services in Consul via DNS interface requires specific structure of the service FQDN as described in this link for standard lookups ([Conusl DNS stadard lookup](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/dns.html#standard-lookup))

FQDN of the service registered with Consul must be in the form:

```
<service>.service[.datacenter].<domain>
```

where `<service>` is the name of your service registered with Consul, in your case `webapp` or `webserver`. The `<domain>` is consul domain as defined in your `consul.json`. `[datacenter]` is optional, and Consul server will return services for the datacenter to which it belongs. Since you haven't defined it in `consul.json` it's `dc1`.

So your `dig` query should look like this:

```
dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600  webapp.service.bino.inc
```

or

```
dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600  webserver.service.bino.inc
```

Optionally you can try adding datacenter to FQDN. Your `dig` query should look like this, and should return same response as those above as you are running single DC single node Consul cluster:

```
dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600  webserver.service.dc1.bino.inc
```

I hope this helps solve your problem.